# NPN BJT + P-Channel MOSFET relay circuit

Tags: mosfet, switches, relay, bjt, boost

[image]

Bit of a newbie here, does this look as if it will function correctly?  I want to use it as a relay-type circuit to use a 3.3V from a MCU pinout to send 12 V over the load, but the results are looking quite bad in LTSpice.

Comment: There is a schematic builder embedded in the question interface, please use that to add your circuit into this question.

Comment: @Bottle My first question is if you placed a reasonable load on the output, or not. (An unloaded output doesn't always tell you what you need to see. Especially when there are parasitics floating about.) (Also, you left a 'user' name in your diagram -- the .lib directories. Not sure if you wanted that, or not.)

Comment: Swap pin 2 and 3 of the PFET, drain at +12 V is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Periblepsis was right, I was missing a ground on my load!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the circuit in your post.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBiUOS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And here is your output.

[image]

As pointed out in the comments, you are lacking a realistic load. We could simply add a load resistor, if it were significantly greater than the R5, or we could use R5 as the load. Perhaps that is what was intended.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhQSBK.png)</sup>

Now you get a much cleaner output.

[image]

There is one other change that I would recommend. R3 is only necessary if the current through the collector of Q1 is excessive. As the circuit stands, the current through Q1 simulates as having peaks of about 3 mA.

[image]

If we remove R3 thus,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYaA7N.png)</sup>

The current peaks only reach a bit above 8 mA.

[image]

If you used a MOSFET with a much higher gate capacitance, you might need a gate resistor between Q1 and the gate. But in this case, there is no issue. You can omit R3.